# Replit not able to use libuuid.so.1 system level package

Tags: replit

I am working on replit to start my LLM Chain based work but it is throwing me the issue of this libuuid.so.1 system level package do not exist despite on using the find command and getting the locations

[Issue Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO9F3.png)

[Issue image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVYk3.png)

Even on getting the result I used export

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib
```

to solve and fix but still it is giving me this issue again please help me.

I tried this:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/mnt/nixmodules/nix/store/acvafmp652dj67f4g3sdx68n2mg1afz4-util-linux-minimal-2.38.1-lib/lib/libuuid.so.1`
```

but I'm still getting the same error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `binutils` is installed or not,

Replit probably uses Ubuntu, so `apt install binutils` should tell you whether it's installed or not.

**Binutils**: *GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities*

Faced a similar problem once, installing binutils solved it.